# How to save file using ionic and ngCordova?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

on my app I a JSON file that I ready some data from it and display to the user. This file does not get update very often, but when it does I need to update the file when the user opens the app.

I saw that I can use ngCordova (org.apache.cordova.file) plugin to do that, but I'm not sure what folder I should put my file. Right now I have the file on my www/data folder, can I update files on that folder? Or do I need to move my file to another folder?

Comment: The `www/data` folder refers to Project sources and you cannot store data there. The storage is based on what platform you use, for example for Android it should be on sdcard. Anyways all manipulations with file system happens natively and not in Javascript

Answer (score 1):

**iOS**: You can save your files in documents directory of your application using cordova.file.documentsDirectory to get the directory's path.

**Android**: You can save your files on sdcard in files directory using cordova.file.externalDataDirectory to get the directory's path.

In all cases, I create a custom directory that contains all my files